# How to convert normal script to use in reactjs function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not well aware with reactjs. I am converting a script tag in reactjs to use inside the function components. Below is the script tag code

```
    <script>

        function videoslider(links){
            document.querySelector(".slider").src = links;
        }

    </script>
```

when I tried to use this in function component as given below

```
        videoslider = (links) => {
            document.querySelector(".slider").src = links;
        }

    or
   
    const videoslider = links => {
        document.querySelector(".slider").src = links;
}
return (
    <div class="container">
        <video src="1.mp4" class="slider" autoplay loop muted controls></video>

        <ul>
            <li onclick="videoslider('1.mp4')"><video src="1.mp4"></video></li>
            <li onclick="videoslider('2.mp4')"><video src="2.mp4"></video></li>
            <li onclick="videoslider('3.mp4')"><video src="3.mp4"></video></li>
            <li onclick="videoslider('4.mp4')"><video src="4.mp4"></video></li>
            <li onclick="videoslider('5.mp4')"><video src="5.mp4"></video></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

then it's gave me the error that videoslider is not declared. Where I did wrong. Any suggestion much appreciate. thanks

Comment: You *really* should read an introductory guide to React before you start trying to write stuff using it. Updating an attribute value when something is clicked on is really introductory level stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useState` hook to solve this problem. In your case for example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [sliderSrc , setSliderSrc] = useState("");
  const videoslider = (links) => {
    setSliderSrc(links);
  };

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <video
        src="1.mp4"
        className="slider"
        src={sliderSrc}
        autoplay
        loop
        muted
        controls
      ></video>

      <ul>
      <li onClick={()=>videoslider('1.mp4')}>
          <video src="1.mp4"></video>
        </li>
        <li onClick={()=>videoslider('2.mp4')}>
          <video src="2.mp4"></video>
        </li>
        <li onClick={()=>videoslider('3.mp4')}>
          <video src="3.mp4"></video>
        </li>
        <li onClick={()=>videoslider('4.mp4')}>
          <video src="4.mp4"></video>
        </li>
        <li onClick={()=>videoslider('5.mp4')}>
          <video src="5.mp4"></video>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to resort to a ref instead of state for this.

Comment: So what you suggest? @Quentin

Comment: Using state. As I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Review it please @Quentin